# Where is Cluster point style in new Carto?

Tags: carto, clustering

In the old interface for CartoDB (Carto Editor?) overlapping points could be displayed as clusters allowing users to click on a cluster to distribute the points visually and select one to read the pop-up. The Cluster style seems to be missing form the new Carto Builder interface.

Am I missing the style option for this or has this been removed from the new version of Carto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ask CARTO Support about the status of Cluster visualization.

Right now you have some workarounds using [cluster](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/calculate-clusters-of-points) and centroid analysis tools, and some labeling and styling techniques. As seen in these three demos:

- [Sales Retail Demo](https://builder-demo.carto.com/builder/b5a3bd38-d8e2-43d8-9116-a1c591b3dd48/embed)
- [Sales Territory Analysis Demo](https://builder-demo.carto.com/builder/85aef0c3-7598-4627-a52a-21e38b78b4a7/embed)
- [Police Stations Location Demo](https://builder-demo.carto.com/builder/0876e726-e73f-11e6-82a3-0e233c30368f/embed)

[image: cluster]

Finally, CARTO is an OS project. You can comment, add feature requests and PR in [their working repositories](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb).

**Disclosure**: I am a Solutions Engineer at CARTO